# completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction runs multiple times

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am using below typed code to handle in app purchases in my app. In completeTransaction I unlock premium content by calling provideContentForProductIdentifier. Mostly it runs only one time but, some times it runs multiple times.

```
- (void)completeTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction 
{
    NSLog(@"completeTransaction...");

    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];

    [self validateReceiptForTransaction:transaction];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
}
```

Please help!

Comment: How many times? Under what conditions? As a side note, you may want to think about doing validation first, and then only if that succeeds unlocking content.

Comment: @ChrisPrince random times, No specific conditions. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same problem. In my case I forgot to removeTransactionObserver. So it still contained the earlier product id. Add this to remove the purchased product id after finishing the transaction.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    NSLog(@"Purchase removedTransactions");

    // Release the transaction observer since transaction is finished/removed.
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] removeTransactionObserver:self];
}
```

Comment: Seems incorrect to me. Any unprocessed transactions will still be pending.